# Prevent exceptions in Rubygem that cannot communicate with its associated web service?

Tags: ruby, exception, captcha, exit, handle

I am using a RubyGem (DeathByCaptcha) that makes HTTP calls to deathbycaptcha.com.  Every so often the HTTP request times out or fails for some other unknown reason, and my Ruby scripts exits with an exception.  I am trying to automate repeated instances of this method ("decode") and I am trying to determine if there is a way to prevent an error in this method from exiting the whole script.

EDIT:  Since I'm bound to get flamed on here, I will mention upfront that the purpose of this is to determine the effectiveness of different captcha options on my website's registration page with common captcha-breakers, because I have had problems with spam signups.

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking. Are you asking how to catch exceptions in Ruby? If not, please post some code about what is failing and what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to prevent the exception from exiting the script.

```
tries = 0

begin
   # risky failing code
rescue
   sleep(1) # sleep n seconds
   tries += 1
   retry if tries <= 3 # retry the risky code again
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to catch the exception that is raised and somehow handle it.

You are looking for something like

```
begin
  # Send HTTP request
rescue WhateverExceptionClassYouGet > error
  # Do something with the error
end
```